# Putting parent-child structure from CSV file in List

Tags: java, list, csv, tree, set

i have scrathing my head few days about this problem. I have CSV file with structure

**Parent Child**

ParA ChildA

ParB ChildB

ParB ChildC

ChildC ChildE

ChildC ChildE
.

.

So,there is more that one roots, and i want to make List or Set, with this structure:

Set made of Lists:

0 ParA ChildA,

1 ParB ChildB,ParB ChildC, ChildC ChildE

.

.
I am working in Java.

I made Set made of unique parents, and i dont know how to add every child to each parent.

End Result is Set which each element will be Diagram with parent-child structure.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need a set of trees, not a set of lists. Have you learned how to implement a tree structure in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it works:

```
class Parent<T> {

    // My name.
    final T name;
    // A children can also be a parent.
    private final List<Parent<T>> children = new ArrayList<>();

    Parent(T name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @param child the child to add
     */
    public void addChild(Parent<T> child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Parent && ((Parent) o).name.equals(name));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(name.toString()).append(":");
        for (Parent<T> child : children) {
            s.append(child.toString());
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
}
// All the parents we have seen so far.
Map<String, Parent<String>> parents = new HashMap<>();

public void add(String parentName, String childName) {
    // Have we seen the parent before?
    Parent<String> parent = parents.get(parentName);
    if (parent == null) {
        // No! Make a new one.
        parents.put(parentName, parent = new Parent<>(parentName));
    }
    // Have we seen the child before?
    Parent<String> child = parents.get(childName);
    if (child == null) {
        // No! Make a new one.
        parents.put(childName, child = new Parent<>(childName));
    }
    // Join them up.
    parent.addChild(child);
}

public void test() {
    add("ParA", "ChildA");
    add("ParB", "ChildB");
    add("ParB", "ChildC");
    add("ChildC", "ChildE");
    add("ChildC", "ChildE");
    for (Parent<String> p : parents.values()) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

prints

```
ParB:ChildB:ChildC:ChildE:ChildE:
ParA:ChildA:
ChildE:
ChildC:ChildE:ChildE:
ChildB:
ChildA:
```

which may be what you were hoping for.

I have not dealt with the potential issue of adding the same child to a parent more than once.

Comment: Adding same child to parent is not problem. In a fact my biggest issue is removing child's which have been added to parent from the list...in this case it would be removing nodes: ChildE: , ChildB, ChildA.. thanks